# ActiveMq and Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am new to spring boot and am trying to write a consumer using spring boot

Below is my snippet:

```
application.properties
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:8161
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin

SampleActiveMQApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class SampleActiveMQApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceAddPayeeApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Consumer.java

@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "queue/msgQueue")
    public void receiveQueue(String text) {
        System.out.println("inside consumer");
        System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```

I am getting the below error

```
2018-04-23 07:08:08.277  WARN 9196 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue/msgQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Disposed due to prior exception
2018-04-23 07:08:08.292 ERROR 9196 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue/msgQueue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:8161
```

Please assist:

Comment: Try to check if the host or the port is accessible from the location where your code is running.

Comment: Are you executing your publisher and subscriber from same host?

Comment: I am publishing from node js and am trying to consume from spring boot. Node is able to publish.

Comment: as i see, you use an external ActiveMQ running on the localhost, have you tried a command line "telnet localhost 8161" ? can you post more logs

Comment: I am able to access the ActiveMq from my browser using localhost:8161

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that your broker listens on your specified port 8161? By default, Active-mq admin management consoles listens on port 8161 which is accessible over the browser, and the broker listens on 61616. You may need to confirm that. You can check out for more information [here](https://activemq.apache.org/getting-started#Listenport)